# Unable to track fields of Order Summary Objects

Tags: admin

I am unable to track the fields of Order Summary Object I have the system administrator profile assigned to me but i am still unbale to track the fields.
By tracking i mean set History tracking button on the fields and relationship page of an object.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! What exactly do you mean by "track" - to view and/or edit them, or audit them, or something else? Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/382251/edit) your question to add any clarification or additional information.

Comment: @Moonpie by track i mean the Set History Tracking button on the fields and relationship page of an object.

Comment: Are you a system admin?

Comment: yes i am system Admin

Answer (score 2):

Objects mentioned in [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.tracking_field_history.htm&type=5) are available for history tracking. Order Summary object is not supported for history tracking.

Kindly review limitation [here](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdmR2UAJ/order-summary-field-history-tracking).

Comment: Note that there is an open idea suggestion to enable Field History Tracking for the Order Summary object:
https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000NLKoTUAX/enable-track-field-history-for-order-summary-and-fulfillment-order